# Panel like Bootstrap with a picture

Tags: html, css, image, box

I have a question. I want to make a panel/box like the Panel in Bootstrap 3 with a header background.

I made a little sketch in paint, that you can see how I mean it.

I tried adding a class to my box with a background as the image, but then my text below is ON the picture. I even tried making a new class IN the box div but it seems that is not the best option to do, also bootstrap also didnt made it like that and if I use padding the image also applied on the padding. I only want the content below to apply to my padding.

[THE SKETCH, THE RED PART IS THE IMAGE it has 100% width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9UG8.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Post the code you have so far

Comment: CSS: http://pastebin.com/GdP4iivc
HTML: http://pastebin.com/P8FXC2SM

Comment: here is also a jsbin http://jsbin.com/rekowukece

Comment: nvm: im such a noob. I just applied the padding to my content, not the whole box. its working also.